# Is there a way to get the text inside a character in a string using C# Regular Expression?

Tags: c#

So far, this is the sample I've made. What I really accomplished is to get every text inside the Open Curly "{" and Closing Curly "}" braces.

Sample Text:

```
var sampleText = {Id:11} this is a sample text {Id:11} > {Id:12} > {Id:      13} text.
```

Code:

```
var ans12 = Regex.Match(sampleText, @"{(.*?)}");
```

Actual Output: IS FAILED

```
Id:11
```

Need Output: IS PASS

```
Id:11
Id:11
Id:12
Id:13
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Rex.Matches` method, which will return a collection of objects that match the regex. Each will have a property of .Value and .Index. So your code becomes:

```cs
var ans12 = Regex.Matches(sampleText, @"{(.*?)}");
```

Now you will need to iterate through the collection:

```cs
foreach (var match in ans12)
{

    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `ans12.NextMatch()`?

Regex.Match stores multiple results in it.

```
    var sampleText ="{Id:11} this is a sample text {Id:11} > {Id:12} > {Id:      13} text.";
    var ans12 = Regex.Match(sampleText, @"{(.*?)}");
    ans12.ToString().Dump();
    ans12 = ans12.NextMatch();
    ans12.ToString().Dump();
    ans12 = ans12.NextMatch();
    ans12.ToString().Dump();
    ans12 = ans12.NextMatch();
    ans12.ToString().Dump();
    ans12 = ans12.NextMatch();
    ans12.ToString().Dump();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YfJNKP)

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to remove the spaces from the string parts, you can use this simple pattern (simple to change/adapt, if necessary) to return strings that match your *Need Output*:

Note: `.{2}` matches `Id`, but if you always have `Id` and in the same upper/lower case, then use that instead.
Use a StringBuilder if the text is long and you need to cache these strings.

```
var sampleText = "{Id:11} this is a sample text {Id:11} > {Id:12} > {Id:      13} text";
var matches = Regex.Matches(sampleText, @"{(.{2}:)\s*(\d+)}");
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

The full match, m.Value, is of course `{Id:11}`, `{Id:      13}` etc.

Prints:

```
Id:11
Id:11
Id:12
Id:13
```